# when Video element is full screen the custom controls just gets blocked be the full screen video

Tags: javascript, css

Okay, I have a video element with custom controls, but I have no idea why when I make the video full screen by double click, the custom control which I've made just gets blocked behind the video, I gave the video z-index and also to the controls but the control panel is always behind the full screened video, this is the code.

```js
"use strict"
const videoEvents = ['click', 'dblclick', 'mouseenter', 'mousedown', 'mousemove', 'change'];
const videoEventDistributer = document.querySelector('.videoPlayerContainer');
const mainVideo = document.querySelector('.mainVideo');
const videoPlayerControlerContainer = document.querySelector('.videoPlayerControlerContainer');
const btnFullscreen = document.querySelector('.btnFullscreen');
const btnExitFullscreen = document.querySelector('.btnExitFullscreen');
let turnOnController = false;
const fullscreenManager = () => {
  if (document.fullscreenElement !== mainVideo) {
    mainVideo.requestFullscreen();
    btnFullscreen.classList.remove('active');
    btnExitFullscreen.classList.add('active');
    videoEventDistributer.style.setProperty('width', '100vw');
    videoEventDistributer.style.setProperty('height', '100vh');
    videoPlayerControlerContainer.style.setProperty('top', 'calc(100vh - 40px)');
  }
  if (document.fullscreenElement === mainVideo) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
    btnExitFullscreen.classList.remove('active');
    btnFullscreen.classList.add('active');
    videoEventDistributer.style.setProperty('width', '80vh');
    videoEventDistributer.style.setProperty('height', 'calc(45vh + 40px)');
    videoPlayerControlerContainer.style.setProperty('top', '45vh');

  }
}

//
videoEvents.forEach(videoEvent => {

  videoEventDistributer.addEventListener(videoEvent, event => {

    if (event.type === 'click') {

      if (event.target === mainVideo) {
        if (mainVideo.paused) {
          mainVideo.play();
        } else {
          mainVideo.pause();
        }

      }

    }

    if (event.type === 'dblclick') {
      fullscreenManager();

    }


    if (event.type === 'mouseeneter') {


    }

    if (event.type === 'mousemove') {


    }

    if (event.type === 'mousedown') {

    }

    if (event.type === 'change') {

    }



  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: steelblue;
}

.videoPlayerContainer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 80vh;
  height: calc(45vh + 40px);
  background: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.mainVideo {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
}

.videoPlayerControlerContainer {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  transform: translateY(0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 45vh;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: transform .3s;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  gap: 25px;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 50% 20% 1fr;
}

.videoPlayerControlerContainer.active {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.btnPause,
.btnPlay {
  height: 25px;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
}

.btnPause.active,
.btnPlay.active {
  display: block;
}

.progressBar {
  width: 100%;
}

.audioBar {
  width: 80%;
}

.btnFullscreen,
.btnExitFullscreen {
  height: 25px;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
}

.btnFullscreen.active,
.btnExitFullscreen.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="videoPlayerContainer">
    <video class="mainVideo" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"></video>
    <div class="videoPlayerControlerContainer">
      <img src="pause.svg" alt="" class="btnPause active">
      <img src="play.svg" alt="" class="btnPlay">
      <input class="progressBar" type="range" name="" id="">
      <input class="audioBar" type="range" name="" id="">
      <img class="btnFullscreen active" src="goFullScreen.svg" alt="">
      <img class="btnExitFullscreen" src="exitFullScreen.svg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to be able to put my controler in front of the full screened video, currenty it gets resized pretty well when the video is full screen but it is behind the video, looking forward to you tips and comments!

Comment: In the example above, the green controlls bar is in front of the video for me. Also in full-screen mode.

Comment: yeah because no video is present.

Comment: I submitted an edit to your question with a demo video. When I tested it with that, it worked as you want it to. What browser are you testing this in?

Comment: I'm testing it on Firefox, the Chrome shows the default controls even though there is no attribute available on video element.but Firefox works fine on that matter, you think it's from Firefox, dude, I tested on Chrome also, its not from Firefox.

Comment: You can check this post  https://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/ . In this post they discuss this issue clearly. You can hide the native controls in full screen using this code video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}. I work with your code but unfortunately can't able to show your custom controll. May be you can find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this post [Hiding Native HTML5 Video Controls in Full-Screen Mode](https://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/) . In this post they discuss this issue clearly. You can hide the native controls in full screen using this code

```
video::-webkit-media-controls { display:none !important; }
```

I work with your code but unfortunately can't able to show your custom controll. May be you can find something

Comment: dude, that is weird, I keep changing the z-index as the guideline says but it doesn't do anything, still custom controls are behind the full screened video, something has changed?

Comment: Yes this is what I find when I tried. That's really weird. That's why I said may be you try and find something

Comment: Okay, I got it, the element which is going to be full screened should not be the video it must be the container of video and our custom controller, you check for the videoEventDistributer element in this code to see whether or not it's the full screened element, if not, then you full screen it .